What historical era & region might this chair design be from?
I have been trying to track down the region and historical era of these chairs. Apologies for the quality of the photo but it's gone through a few wringers.
I think these are 19th century mass-produced institutional chairs - but I can't find any design online that matches them - particularly the raised ears.
Hoping someone might be able to point out any significant design elements that suggest one era or another.
Thanks


The quality of the image, and that it's the only one, is unfortunate and it may prove to be fatal to the enquiry regrettably. Still, a worthy endeavour so +1. Are you able to provide any contextual clues that aren't in the Q?

I suspect the best you're going to be able to do here, due to the lack of visible key details, is some vague date prior to the date of the photo itself, assuming that's known. "particularly the raised ears" extremely common in vernacular 'stick chairs' for what it's worth. A further detail that's worth bearing in mind is that even with the number seen it's possible this was produced by a local craftsperson. Even if there's knowledge of numerous more a local source is still a possibility. And local can mean idiosyncratic design elements that make any firm dating much harder, or impossible.

Really the only possible starting point would be the origin of the photo itself. Do you know where and/or when it was taken? Where did you come across this photo?

It is a band t-shirt photo that is essentially part of an internet treasure hunt - so the source is deliberately obscure - about 1/3 of photos in the series have been identified and they relate to art and artist studios, cemetaries, religious buildings and legal buildings. This could be from a waiting room, a funeral home or a classroom related to any of the above. I was hoping there was something distinctive about the chair style that might provide a lead since I've looked at thousands of Google Images so far. The provenance of other photos is global and from all along the timeline.

the chairs resemble the vintage wooden chairs I saw in use in an American office/adult trade school administration building in 1990. They were made of oak and sturdy as heck. They were factory made - or perhaps prison-made - between 1950’s and 1970’s.
Perhaps the theme of the band’s album or tour will provide a clue. Presumably their scavenger hunt is related to that theme.
